# form_submit event fires in GTM but not in GA4

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, mailerlite

I'm using the [Enhanced Measurement](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9216061?hl=en) form tracking for a [Mailerlite](https://www.mailerlite.com/help/how-to-create-an-embedded-form) embedded HTML and JS form.

This fires two events `form_start` (user interacts with form) and `form_submit` (user submits form).

Both `form_start` and `form_submit` are firing correctly in GTM debug mode:

[image]

But `form_submit` does not fire in GA4 debug mode:

[image: GA4 form_submit does not fire]

I can see there are a lot more `form_start` >>> `form_submit` events in the event analytics for the site, which suggests this isn't working properly.

I'm only semi-technical, so any help/ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your first screenshot suggests there's no tag fired when form_submit datalayer event occurred. please post a screenshot of your trigger pls.

Comment: As I'm using Enhanced Measurements, should this actually fire a tag e.g. the GA4 tag? 

The only trigger I have setup is a custom one for `outbound_clicks`.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same issue

Comment: Sadly not! Please let me know if you find the answer though!

Answer (score 0):

When events are firing correctly in Google Tag Manager (GTM) but not appearing in Google Analytics 4 (GA4), there are several potential issues to investigate:

1. **Configuration in GTM**: Ensure that your GTM tags for `form_submit` are correctly set up to send data to GA4. It's possible to have a GTM event that isn't tied to a GA4 tag, so make sure the tag is there and correctly configured. Also check MeasurementId you have set in the configuration Tag.
2. **Filters in GA4**: Make sure there are no filters or configurations in GA4 that could be blocking or altering the incoming `form_submit` events.
3. **Event Naming**: Double-check the naming convention you're using for the events in GTM and ensure they match what you're looking for in GA4.
4. **Preview Mode Discrepancies**: Remember that GA4's DebugView and GTM's Preview mode don't always sync up perfectly in real-time. There can be a delay, especially if you're firing many events in quick succession. Refresh and wait a bit to see if the events eventually come through.
5. **Blocking Scripts**: If you have any other scripts or browser extensions (like ad blockers) running, they might interfere with some of the tracking events.
6. **JavaScript Errors**: Look into the browser's console for any JavaScript errors that might be interrupting the tracking sequence. Sometimes, even if the `form_start` event is firing, a subsequent JavaScript error could prevent the `form_submit` event from firing.
7. **Tag Sequencing**: Ensure that no other tags in GTM are firing and potentially disrupting the `form_submit` tag. You can set up tag sequencing in GTM if you need one tag to fire before another.
8. **Network Issues**: Using the browser's developer tools, inspect the network tab to see if the request to GA4 is being made and if there are any issues with it. For example: console.log(" GA Event Fired");

[image]

Finally, consider using a tool like the Google Analytics Debugger (a Chrome extension) or the GA4 DebugView in the GA4 property itself. These tools can provide more insights into what's being sent to GA, which might help pinpoint any issues. I personally use **datasLayer**.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue too - had some advice and was told the following:

Normally this happens when the form submit is done using java script, so the actual HTML form never actually gets submitted.

Unfortunately if this is the case (and assuming the form doesn’t go to a thank you page) then you would need some custom tags setup in Tag Manager to track the forms.

Hope it helps you!